# Ubuntu 12.04 Hangs with Software Center open then opening Dash Home

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I have a Dell D610 with Intel graphics, 1 GB RAM. I have tested the hard drive and RAM and both are fine.

**When I open the Software Center, then the Dash home, my system locks up.**

The *mouse cursor* moves but is unresponsive, if I try to right or left click anything. The *keyboard* is totally unresponsive and I have to hold the *power button* to power off!

I have *reinstalled* from CD, did *all updates* but the issue persists. I tried using the track pad only, and I plugged in an external mouse also but no change. 
Everything else works great!

I am sick of running Vista and have no love for Metro!
Thanks for any suggestions!
(On a scale of 1 to 10 [Newbie - Expert] I am about 3.)

Comment: can you reproduce it everytime? Then i suggest filing a bug. [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/a/137915/45659) <shameless self-promotion>

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, It happens  every time with my primary account. I tested with guest account and I had a similar issue but was able to use the keyboard to get out of it ; but the system responded very slowly.

Comment: bug it is, then. btw, does magic keys work? Try Ctrl+Alt+K and report results. And please take time to file a bug. <against compiz or unity, for a start.Once the problem is pointed out, it can be reassigned to proper package.>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mahesh, I just reinstalled for the 3rd time this time I was connected to the internet (other times I was not). I did all updates, configured my wireless (only device that needed a driver .. broadcom card) and EVerything works fine. I have 8 tabs open now in FF, software center, + opened dash home -Success all is well. I can not wait to install this OS on my Asus G73 with SSD!!! 
Yes all the KB shortcut keys work. I held the magic key by mistake and many KB options appeared! What an AWESOME OS!

Comment: Special Thanks to Mahesh, and to the community I have learned a lot from this forum already!